# How to split Vim windows when using NERDTree?

Tags: vim, nerdtree, netrw

I'm a recent convert to [NERDTree](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) having used [NETRW](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1075) for many years. I'm struggling to know how to specify where the buffer will be placed in a split.

- Sometimes I want to open the split vertically:

  - New buffer on the right (`:Vex!` with NETRW).
  - New buffer on the left (`:Vex` with NETRW).
- Sometimes I want to open the split horizontally

  - New buffer on top ( `:Sex` with NETRW).
  - New buffer on top ( `:Hex` with NETRW).

**Is there some equivalent with NERDTree?** I can open things in a vertical split (`s`) or in a horizontal split (`i`), but it seems that I can't lways predict where the new buffer is going to be.

Comment: You might be interested in [this article](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/) as a frame challenge. It directly mentions the difficulty you experience here.

Comment: Nice find @D.BenKnoble I should stick to using NETRW if I want the functionality